# Transfer files from s3 to SFTP server

Tags: php, amazon-s3, sftp

I have logic to upload images to s3 in php. I need to upload the same set of images in a SFTP server. In my view there are 2 options. First is to find a logic to upload image from my local to the server, when I am uploading images to s3 and the other option is to write some script to transfer the images from s3 to sftp server. I need the same set of images to be in the server and s3.

Out of the 2 approaches, which one is optimal? Is there any other way to approach my requirement? Any sample php script available for local to SFTP file transfer, if yes please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure which one is optimal, but I can definitely see a potential issue with option #1. If you perform the second upload (i.e. from your "local" server to the SFTP server) during the first upload, you make PHP wait on that operation before returning the response to the client. This could cause some unnecessary hanging for the user agent connecting to the local server.

I would explore option #2 first. If possible, look into [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). This is a way to mount a remote filesystem over SSH. It uses the SFTP to transfer files. This may be a possible solution where all you have to do is write the file once to the local server's filesystem and then again to the mounted, remote filesystem. SSHFS would take care of the transfer for you.

Comment: Currently I have a cms kind of web application to upload the data. Current requirement is that, I have to upload images from this cms(http) to another server running a https site. I have option to upload images to s3 from the cms. The requirement is to add another feature so that the images are going to the https site's sub folder also.